# Ltac: repeating a tactic n times with backtracking

Tags: coq, dependent-type, theorem-proving, coq-tactic, ltac

Suppose I have a tactic like this (taken from HaysTac), that searches for an argument to specialize a particular hypothesis with:

```
Ltac find_specialize_in H :=
  multimatch goal with
  | [ v : _ |- _ ] => specialize (H v)
end.
```

However, I'd like to write a tactic that searches for `n` arguments to specialize a tactic with. The key is that it needs to backtrack. For example, if I have the following hypotheses:

```
y : T
H : forall (x : T), x = y -> P x
x1 : T
x2 : T
Heq : x1 = y
```

If I write `do 2 (find_specialize_in H)`, it might choose `x2` to instantiate it, then fail trying to find a second argument. So I need my repeat loop to be able to backtrack with which arguments it chooses to specialize earlier arguments.

Is it possible to do this? How can I make a tactic loop that backtracks with its choices of previous iterations?

Comment: As I answered in coq club, this should already do what you want. Are you wiring the tactic just being incomplete"